# Question regarding @property

Tags: objective-c, ios4, iphone

I'm kinda new in Obj-C and I would like to ask why everything need to write something like this?

```
@property (_something, _something) NSString* name;
```

What is the @property indicates for? 
Why we need to put _something in the bracket?

PS: I know there is no _something, it should be nonatomic, retain, copy and so on. Since it has so many options, that's why I simply put a word to indicate the content inside the bracket. 
(Where can I get all the list of available options?)

Thanks :D

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@property` indicates that you are defining a property, which is at the basic level just [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) that allows you to do `variable = object.property` and `object.property = value` instead of `variable = [object property]` and `[object setProperty:value]`. If you really wanted, you could skip declaring any properties and just declare the getter and setter methods directly and the runtime would hardly notice the difference.

The things inside the parentheses modify the property. Many are only useful for properties whose getter and/or setter implementations are created for you using `@synthesize` in the @implementation block. For example, `assign` (the default) says that the value set is just set; `retain` says that the object set will automatically have its `retain` method called (and the previous object, if any, will have `release` called); and `copy` says that the object will have its `copy` called.

A list of possible attributes is in [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW2).

Comment: +1 particularly for the documentation link. Don't confuse properties and dot notation, though -- I wouldn't call properties syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 1):

The `@property` directive is simply a promise that the class provides accessors for the given identifier. Options given after the directive (copy, nonatomic, etc.) specify how the accessors behave. That's really all there is to it.

Related syntax includes the directives `@dynamic` and `@synthesize` and dot notation. The two directives are mutually exclusive and tell the compiler that you'll supply the accessors or that the compiler should supply the accessors, respectively. Dot notation is the syntactic sugar that Anomie mentioned -- it's meant for accessing properties, but you're not required to formally declare a property to use it.